# Multiple GPUs and Multiple displays

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I am new to Ubuntu Studio and I have version 19.10.

My question is: How do I get multiple displays and multiple GPUs to work?

I have 2 GTX 1080s and 2 1070s in my system. I use the 1080s in SLI on windows. I have three displays two connected to the 1070s (one per card) and one for the 1080s (in SLI).

I don't have to have SLI in Linux, but I don't want to use xinerama. I would prefer having base mosaic, but I haven't had much luck getting it to work. Is there anyway I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a different compositor. One that is compatible with the X11 config.

Then you have to point nvidia-config to xorg.conf

Comment: I'm switched to compton which has its on config file do I point nvidia config to that file because I'm sure its already pointed to the xorg.conf. I've tried editing that file and can only get the displays to work in xinerama.

Comment: the way i did it on two cards was disabling nvidia-config (keeping the modules) and letting xorg config the screens.
I was using a 1060 and a 660 at the time - so they were as different as could be.